# how to change order of the numbers in table

Tags: c#

I am new at learning how to make 10 or 20 or 25 number table. I am doing 10 number table. For example I have 4 number table 1,2,3,4 and want at the end to write it like 4,3,2,1 - can someone tell me how to do that?

My program

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] p = new int[10] { 2, 9, 13, 3, 50, -8, -30, 0, 1, 4 };
        int vsota = 0;
        float povprecje = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("p [{0}] = {1,3}", i, p[i]);
            vsota += p[i];
        }
        povprecje = (float)vsota/p.Length;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Vsota = {0}!", vsota);
        Console.WriteLine("Povprecje = {0}!", povprecje);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Comment: What is a table? I'm not following your question. Can you put up some code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] p = new int[10] { 2, 9, 13, 3, 50, -8, -30, 0, 1, 4 };
            int vsota = 0;
            float povprecje = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("p [{0}] = {1,3}", i, p[i]);
                vsota += p[i];
            }
            povprecje = (float)vsota/p.Length;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Vsota = {0}!", vsota);
            Console.WriteLine("Povprecje = {0}!", povprecje);
            Console.ReadKey(true);

Comment: my numbers are written as you see but I would like to change that - change the order of numbers - first 4, 1, o, -30

Comment: Is the question how to reverse an array?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Linq's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145016.aspx) [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343617.aspx) and [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292260.aspx) methods to sort a collection. In your example:

```
int[] p = new int[10] { 2, 9, 13, 3, 50, -8, -30, 0, 1, 4 };
p = p.OrderByDescending( x => x ).ToArray();
```

**Edit**: added the expression to the OrderByDescending method. Also, Linq is for the 3.5 and above framework and requires reference to the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: when I put that in like you did I got error "No overload for method 'OrderByDescending().ToArra()'takes 0 arguments

Comment: @KristyMaitz - see the updated example with the included expression for the OrderByDescending method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a List you can do it with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> table = new List<int>();

        table.Add(1);
        table.Add(2);
        table.Add(3);
        table.Add(4);

        foreach(int item in table)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        table.Reverse();

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(int item in table)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please look at my program and tell me where to put it? so the numbers would be revers?

Comment: -1 as the OP is wanting to know how to sort a list of integers in descending order; not how to reverse the order of a list of integers.

Comment: +1 OP's comment on the question gives the order 4, 1, 0, -30, which is indeed the reverse order not a sorted order.

Comment: let just say I am new to that topic. Sorry for problems

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is that you want to reverse an array. So if you have this array:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

You want to reverse the elements so that they're `{ 3, 2, 1, 0 }`.

The key is that you want to swap elements. For example, if you were to write:

```
// swap first and last elements
int temp = a[0];
a[0] = a[a.Length - 1];
a[a.Length - 1] = temp;
```

Then your array would be `{ 3, 1, 2, 0 }`.

The idea, then, is to swap `a[0]` and `a[length-1]`. Then swap `a[1]` and `a[length-2]`, etc. until you've swapped each item with its counterpart.

You can do this with a single loop.

By the way, the `Reverse` method only works on the `List` type. For arrays, the `Reverse` method is actually a LINQ extension method, and you need to create a new array. For example:

```
int[] b = a.Reverse.ToArray();
```

Comment: when I put that in Length stays black and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

To sort a one-dimensional array, you could call the Array.Sort() and/or Array.Reverse() methods. Updating your example, you could do something like the following:

```
int[] p = new int[10] { 2, 9, 13, 3, 50, -8, -30, 0, 1, 4 };
int vsota = 0;
float povprecje = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("p [{0}] = {1,3}", i, p[i]);
    vsota += p[i];
}
povprecje = (float)vsota/p.Length;
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Vsota = {0}!", vsota);
Console.WriteLine("Povprecje = {0}!", povprecje);
Console.ReadKey(true);

// Sort (low to high) the int[] by calling the Array.Sort() method
Array.Sort(p);
foreach(int i in p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

// Sort (high to low) the int[] by calling the Array.Reverse() method
Array.Reverse(p);
foreach(int i in p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the array:

```
p = p.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an update to @Metro Smurf's LINQ solution:

```
int[] p = new int[10] { 2, 9, 13, 3, 50, -8, -30, 0, 1, 4 };
p = p.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
```